# Bash aliases du - sh + sort

Tags: bash, sorting, du, aliases

Here is my aim: 
I want to see disk usage AND have the list sorted by size AND make it an alias.

I read on the forum that `du -hs somedirectory |sort -h` would do the first two jobs, which is true. 
How can I put this in my .bash_aliases ?

The next line works, but I cannot choose the directory anymore

`alias du="du -hs * |sort -h"`

Thank you for your help !

R

Comment: add the complete command you tried after adding the alias... suggestion, use something other than `du` for your alias... if you want to pass directory name to your shortcut, you need to use function instead of alias

Comment: When I am in a directory, I would like to be able to do `du ./somedirectory/*` or `du *`

Comment: Thanks Sundeep, the function thing is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass dynamic arguments to the first command in `alias`. You need to use `function` to achieve this:

```
dirsize() {
    du -hs $* | sort -h
}
```

Put this in your `.bashrc` file. Then,

```
$ dirsize Development/ Documents/ Videos/
86M Documents/
92M Development/
5.6G Videos/
```

To make an `alias`:

```
$ alias du=dirsize
```

Comment: Works ! Many thanks, I think it was what I was looking for !